# How to return the content of an array carrying multiple data types?

Tags: solidity

```
contract minter {

    //instantiate ERC20 contract
    ERC20 erc20 = ERC20 (0x2C31Db3Cc686CBf0EF2325a468f622137A42Da31);

    //keep track of created ERC20 addresses
    ERC20 [] public tokenList;


    mapping (address => uint) balances;

    //make msg.sender the owner
    address owner_ = msg.sender;

    function createERC20 (string memory name_, string memory symbol_, uint totalSupply_) public {
        erc20 = new ERC20 (name_, symbol_, totalSupply_, owner_);
        tokenList.push(erc20);
    }

    
    
    function getList () public view returns (address [] memory){
        return tokenList();



    }
}
```

I tried to use this contract as a factory for the already deployed contract `ERC20` at the address. The minting appears to work, but I have a problem to track the data of the mints. I thought I could just push the array `tokenList` with the data inside of the `createERC20` function, but I do not get how I can display the contents of the array with the `getList` function. I have seen people using structs to store the data, but is it possible to instantiate `ERC20` to a struct?

I tried multiple different approaches for the getter function, but I just do not seem to find the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your `tokenList` items are of type `contract`. If you return `ERC20[]` from the function, they will get converted to an array of addresses.

```
function getList() public view returns (ERC20[] memory){
    return tokenList;
}
```